# How do I group axlsx file to sort alphabetically by org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by

Org is a column in attendee that's nested in this includes statement.  I want it so that it groups attendee.org alphabetically

```
@meetings = NwMeeting.includes(meeting_attendees: [:attendee]).where(show_id: @show.id)
 @meetings.each do |meeting|
      @nw_attendee_meetings = meeting&.meeting_attendees(&:attendee)
      @nw_attendee_meetings.each do |nw_attendee_meeting|
        attendee = nw_attendee_meeting&.attendee
        data = []
        data << attendee&.org
        data << attendee&.name
        data << meeting&.status&.capitalize
        AxlsxTools.add_row(data) (edited)
```

Comment: Is `org` an association or an attribute? If an attribute then `NwMeeting.includes(meeting_attendees: [:attendee]).where(show_id: @show.id).references(meeting_attendees: [:attendee]).order(Attendee.arel_table[:org].asc)` will work if an association you will need to join it. Also might want to mention how you want to handle empty orgs. Side note wayyyyy too many safe navigation operators.

Comment: You want the meetings with NULL org be placed in front of all records or after them?

Comment: @kevinluo201
in front!

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to list Attendee records, it may be a little bit easier if you switch the "main" model you query to Attendee. Joining the NwMeeting and SELECT the `status` column, then you can just do `ORDER BY attendees.org ASC`, the records with NULL value will be placed in front of others by default.

```rb
@attendees = Attendee.joins(meeting_attendees: :nw_meeting)
  .select("attendees.*, nw_meetings.status AS meeting_status")
  .where(nw_meetings: { show_id: @show.id })
  .order("attendees.org ASC")
  # .order("attendees.org ASC NULL FIRST") if you use PosgreSQL
@attendees.each do |attendee|
  data = []
  data << attendee.org
  data << attendee.name
  data << attendee.meeting_status&.capitalize
  AxlsxTools.add_row(data)
end
```

btw, @engineersmnky 's Arel method is more advanced, and that should work, too :)